# Laravel Excel importacion por trozos (chunk importer) llega a su limite ejecución

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

Tengo una aplicacion que usa Laravel Excel 2.1, con el que intento importar un archivo Excel que pesa 74MB.

Segun la documentacion, para archivos excel pesados o con muchos registros debo usar chunk importer (importacion por trozos): https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/import/chunk.html.

Pero aun asi php me muestra un error de limite de memoria o tiempo de ejecucion agotado.

```
    [2019-07-18 11:17:50] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/vagrant/code/efact/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/String.php:348
Stack trace:
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Log;
use Excel;

class ContribuyenteService
{

    public function cargaMasivaContribuyentes($request)
    {
        Excel::filter('chunk')->load($request->file('file'))->chunk(100, function($results)
        {
                foreach($results as $row)
                {
                    Log::debug($row);
                }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: no esta mal tu codigo. es un problema de configurar tu php para que permita ejecutar procesos mas largos.

Comment: @gbianchi podria servirme en local pero en produccion pienso que seria un problema de seguridad el ampliar el tiempo de ejecucion. yo pensaba que el chunk hacia una peticion por cada 100 registros, si funciona asi no deberia darme ese problema.

Comment: Tu error no dice que no hace eso.. tu error dice que ese proceso tarda mas de 30 segundos.. ni habla del chunk... el chunk debe ser para no llenar la memoria al ser muy grande el excel. Tal vez esto no deberia ser un proceso php disparado por un usuario. habria que ver tu escenario, pero un proceso tan largo no deberia estar regido por una pagina web.. o el usuario se muere esperando que pase algo con su pagina y su navegador..

Comment: Ok, es muy largo el excel, en realidad es un panel para administradores, y tienes razon, voy a limitar cantidad de registros que puede tener el excel o el peso. Puse asi por que esperaba una solución con colas o Jobs, pero tomare el camino corto limitar el peso del excel.

Comment: Si esperabas una solucion con colas o jobs deberias haberlo aclarado. Igual nadie sabe tu arquitectura como poner una respuesta de ese estilo. Subir el archivo y que despues un proceso posterior lo cargue seria algo ideal.

Comment: es que soy nobato xd y me parece genial esa solución de subir el archivo y dejar que un proceso en el servidor se active para ir procesandolo en segundo plano, buscare info al respecto, gracias.